# Associate element with specific section for screen reader announcing but visibly/structurally in another section

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, sections

I am looking for a way to have screen readers announce a particular elements content in my header section even though the element is structurally outside of the header section. is this possible?

Something like:

```
<header id="my_header">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="mylogo.jpg" /></a>
</header>
<main>
    <div section-id="my_header">I want this announced in the header section but displayed in the main section</div>
</main>
```

This is a simplified demonstration of what I am looking for. In my header I have a link that is displayed in the header for desktop resolutions, for mobile this link should appear in the main content section so that it is scrollable with the main content but I want screenreaders to announce it as part of the header. thanks!

Comment: I know you are simplifying the problem for brevity but can you explain a bit further as to why you want to do this? I only question it as you could end up providing a different experience to screen reader users to non screen reader users, which is against accessibility principles. Why can't it stay within the header section on mobile as if it makes sense to have it there on a screen reader would it also make sense to be there for a non screen reader user. Is this due to a space issue or something? We can do this by the way but just wanted to see if there is a better way.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie thanks for your response! It's a design issue where in mobile a header link is moved into the main content so that it doesn't persist in the header but the header is still persisted. Visually it appears above h1 of the main content so I actually want the experience to be the same. Visually it is above and should be announced before the H1 but the link is announced after the h1. In the markup the link is actually moved out of the header tag. Hope this makes sense.